# Connection Aborted in py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying the tutorial samples of py2neo. Sometimes, when I try to create index or get node or any other interaction with neo4j, I get the SocketError: error(10053, 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine'). Is there any way I can detect if the connection is still there in py2neo libs or shall I always call the GraphDatabaseService before queries.

Answer (score 0):

More than 5 years late but googling my 10053 error with neo4j and py2neo sends me to this page.

I got the same error and adding and user solved it for me.

```
CALL dbms.security.createUser('test', 'test', false)
```